# Make a counter stop if it breaks a determined sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter

Brief summary about my question: I'm trying to turn a sequence into a "conditional" sequence -- the input is AN ARRAY made with only true and false which I think will make it harder than it will be if it made of sequence of numbers. The idea is to make it count a sequence of "true" and break when the next input is "false" and returns the bigger count.

```
// If the input is something like [true, true, ... true, true] 
// should return count => input.length

// My issue is to make it break when it have a interruption i. e. 
// [true, true, true, false, true, true, false] 
// should return => the bigger sequence; with my code it returns 5 

function sol(sequence) {
    let count = 0;
    
for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] == true) {
        if (sequence[i] == sequence[i+1]){
            count++;
        }
    }
}

// I tried to add a break; but isn't worked like i wanted
// for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
//     if (sequence[i] == true) {
//         if (sequence[i] == sequence[i+1]){
//             count++;
//         } 
//         if (sequence[i] != sequence[i+1]) {
//             break;
// }
//     }
// }


// I need the counter has bigger (or equals) than 7 otherwise it return a "fail"
if (count >= 7) {
        console.log(count)
    } else {
        console.log('failed')
    } 
}
```

After some explains on the post here's a functional result:

```
  function sol(sequence) {
// Move the "+1" to low then when have no "true" will return 0.
  let count = 0;
  let largestSequence = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] == true) {
      if (sequence[i] == sequence[i + 1]) {
        count++;
      }
    } else {
      if (largestSequence < count) {
        largestSequence = count + 1;
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return Math.max(largestSequence, count);
}
```

And here's the final answer that aced all my weird examples. Thank you [Gulam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6514790/gulam-hussain)

```
let sequenceContinued = false;
let count = 0;
let sequences = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const item = array[i];

  if (item === false && sequenceContinued === true) {
    sequenceContinued = false;
    sequences.push(count);
    count = 0;
    continue;
  }

  if (item === true) {
    sequenceContinued = true;
    count++;
  }

  if (i === array.length - 1 && item === true) {
    sequences.push(count);
  }
}

const longestCount = sequences.length ? Math.max(...sequences) : 0;
```

Comment: You want the count of consequence `true` right?

Comment: So what should `[true, true, true, false, true, true, false]` return? Should it return the longest sequence of trues i.e. 3?

Comment: @GulamHussain yes, sorry if my explanation has not clear as I think it was

Comment: @PaulRooney sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  true,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true
];

let sequenceContinued = false;
let count = 0;
let sequences = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const item = array[i];

  if (item === false && sequenceContinued === true) {
    sequenceContinued = false;
    sequences.push(count);
    count = 0;
    continue;
  }

  if (item === true) {
    sequenceContinued = true;
    count++;
  }

  if (i === array.length - 1 && item === true) {
    sequences.push(count);
  }
}

const longestCount = sequences.length ? Math.max(...sequences) : 0;

console.log(longestCount);
```

Comment: Hey! That worked in simple case, but when I tried a input more complex like: [ false, false, true, true, false, true ] it returns "0" i. e. he stops the count on the second "false". Do you have a idea to fix it?

Comment: in that it case it should return 2, because of `true` at index 2 and 3. right?

Comment: exactly! the bigger will be the input independent of his length or where it was.
i. e. the input [false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true] will return 3

Comment: ohh, so you want the highest count, i'm sorry. okok i got it. updating the answer

Comment: Thinking about it I figured out that it has a "check-in" system. If "true" for login, for example, he will have +1 in his check-in counter and a "false" will break the checkin; what I want will be the same of the bigger checkin of this user

Comment: I have updated the answer, this will give you the longe chain of `true` in an array

Answer (score 0):

```
  function sol(sequence) {
  let count = 1;
  let largestSequence = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    if (sequence[i] == true) {
      if (sequence[i] == sequence[i + 1]) {
        count++;
      }
    } else {
      if (largestSequence < count) {
        largestSequence = count;
        count = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return Math.max(largestSequence, count);
}

var arr = [true, false, true, true, true, true, true];
var solution = sol(arr);
console.log(solution);
```

You can created a separate variable 'largestSequence' and everytime a false value is encountered, it will store the value of count in largestSequence.

At the end the maximum of the two variables-largestSequence and count is returned because it may happen that the largest sequence of trues is not terminated by a false like [true, false, true, true, true, true, true].

Comment: Good answer, but there is an issue this will return 1 in case if array does not contain `true`

Comment: I'm new in coding and I wanna to have a explain why the count reset again to 1. I tried something like that and my count does not have a break i. e. when it has a new sequence of true it return to count from the last value. Can you explain me why?

Comment: This is because count store the number of consecutive trues. Suppose in the array [true,  true, false, true, true, true, true ,false], after the first 2 iterations the count value will be 2. Then it encounters a false value so then 2 is stored in largestSequence variable and count is reset to 1. Then again there are 4 consecutive trues in the array so each time the count value will get incremented and again when a false value in encountered, that count value(if it is bigger than the previous count value) will be stored in largestSequence.